# Question regarding JWK generation using RSA-PSS 4096

Tags: rsa, key-derivation, key-generation

###### Summarized Question:

In the context of JWK generation using RSA-PSS 4096bit with SHA-256, where the public exponent is `"e" = 65537`, is there any situation where the prime number **21863** comes in view?

###### Context:

To start, I'm not well versed with the mechanics of the algorithms discussed here, just the overview.

The question comes from a metapuzzle I'm trying to solve, the mini-puzzle I'm working is a drawing of a rhombus/diamond with the number '21863' written within it and two arrows pointing towards the shape, like so:
[image: illustration of clue]

I'm leaning (using context from previous puzzles) towards this pointing towards JWK format key (RFC 7517) generation using RSA-PSS 4096bit with SHA-256, where the public exponent is "65537".

One possible relation to the two number I've found is [here](https://oeis.org/A265614), where 21863 is a number in the sequence "A set of nine consecutive primes forming a 3 X 3 semimagic square with the smallest magic constant (65573)".

I was wondering if the '21863' number might come up if I used one of the smallest values in the RSA keypair generation? Anyone with better insight on this?